# glDrawElementsInstanced freezes or slow down at 18680 instances

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, opengl-3

I am developing a C++ program to simulate rain.
I am using OpenGL instance feature for rendering an increasing numbers of droplets. (One instance = one droplet)

The program runs fine when calling `glDrawElementsInstances`, until the number of instances reaches 18680. Then, it freezes or produces weird behaviour (huge slowdown, incoherent rendering of instances).

My rendering loop:

```
GLObject GLDrop(*this->_model._drop, *this->_shader); // generate buffer
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(this->_window))
{
     glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
     this->_model._drop->create();
     GLDrop.setDropState();
     glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, this->_model._drop->getElementsSize(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, this->_model._drop->getInstances());
     GLDrop.disableDropState();
     glfwSwapBuffers(this->_window);
     glfwPollEvents();
}
```

My Buffer generating function, called just before the rendering loop:

```
void            GLObject::generateDropBuffers(void)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &this->_vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->_vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->_module.getVerticesSize() * sizeof(GLfloat), this->_module.getVertices(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &this->_ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->_ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->_module.getElementsSize() * sizeof(GLuint), this->_module.getElements(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &this->_pbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->_pbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->_module.getMaxInstances() * DIMENSIONS * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &this->_cbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->_cbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->_module.getMaxInstances() * COLOR_CHANNELS * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
```

Each time Drop.create() is called, a new batch of droplet is created, incrementing the numbers of instances to be drawn to the screen.

```
void            Drop::create(void)
{
    unsigned int    i;
    unsigned int    j;

    if (this->_instances < this->_maxInstances - this->_dropBatch)
    {
        for (GLuint drop = 0; drop < this->_dropBatch; ++drop)
        {
           i = this->_instances * DIMENSIONS;
           j = this->_instances * COLOR_CHANNELS;

           this->_positions[i] = rand() % this->_model._vertexCol * UNIT;
           this->_positions[i + 1] = this->_model._top + 3.0f * UNIT;
           this->_positions[i + 2] = rand() % this->_model._vertexRow * UNIT;

           this->_colors[j] = 0.0f;
           this->_colors[j + 1] = 0.0f;
           this->_colors[j + 2] = 1.0f;
           this->_colors[j + 3] = 1.0f; 
           this->_instances += 1;
        }
     }
}
```

My buffer binding function:

```
void            GLObject::setDropState(void)
{
    GLuint      instances = this->_module.getInstances() - this->_module.getBatchSize();
    GLuint      posOffset = instances * DIMENSIONS;
    GLuint      colorOffset = instances * COLOR_CHANNELS;
    GLuint      posSize = this->_module.getBatchSize() * DIMENSIONS * sizeof(GLfloat);
    GLuint      colorSize = this->_module.getBatchSize() * COLOR_CHANNELS * sizeof(GLfloat);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->_vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(this->_shader.getAPosition(), DIMENSIONS, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(this->_shader.getAPosition());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->_ebo);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->_pbo);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posOffset * sizeof(GLfloat), posSize, this->_module.getPositions() + posOffset);
    glVertexAttribPointer(this->_shader.getAInstance(), DIMENSIONS, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(this->_shader.getAInstance());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->_cbo);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorOffset * sizeof(GLfloat), colorSize, this->_module.getColors() + colorOffset);
    glVertexAttribPointer(this->_shader.getAColors(), COLOR_CHANNELS, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(this->_shader.getAColors());

    glVertexAttribDivisor(this->_shader.getAPosition(), 0);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(this->_shader.getAInstance(), 1);
    glVertexAttribDivisor(this->_shader.getAColors(), 1);
}
```

Tested on:

> NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M 512 MB, MacbookPro.
>
> NVIDIA GeForce 9400M 256 MB, MacbookPro

I don't know what could be the problem. Is there a limitation on the number of instances I can draw in one call ? (I highly doubt that is the case).
I am using buffers way larger than I need, to make sure it is not a memory access issue.

Could it be a memory alignement issue?

OpenGL Manual says this about alignment, but I can't truly understand.

> Clients must align data elements consistent with the requirements of
>   the client platform, with an additional base-level requirement that an
>   offset within a buffer to a datum comprising N bytes be a multiple of
>   N.

Any help would be welcome.

My scene, when 18860 instances of droplets are drawn, before the crash

[image: my scene]
**EDIT:**

While searching on google I found a similar case here: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/181142-glDrawArraysInstanced-max-number-of-instances

The author of the thread has the same problem as me, but with exactly the double of the number of instances (I guess because his GPU memory is 512 and not 256 as mine). Moreover I found that I have different behaviours according to how many instances I add each loop.

For example:
If I add 100 instances per loop, my program freeze.
If I add 200 or more instances per loop, my program slowdown to 4fps.

At the bottom of the link I posted above, the authour exaplains in details the reason of this behavior. Apparently the difference is due to jumping (or not) a specific interval of instances. 
If I add 100 instances per loop I fall into the death-gap (so freeze), but if I add more than 100 I jump over the death-gap (so huge slowdown)

Any idea about this strange macbook "bug"?

Comment: if you use the GL_ARB_debug_output extension (or the equivalent core functions in 4.3+), it will warn you about alignment issues in the driver (assuming the driver supports it - not sure of its availability on Mac... my Mac's video card is very old).

Comment: Maybe you need to interpose a few `glGetError` calls to ensure you aren't exceeding any implementation limits. I don't know of any `glGet` parameters that apply to instance counts. The [OpenGL Extensions Viewer](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/) is a handy utility for limit queries. BTW, are you using vsync? (`glSwapInterval(1)`)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problems with glDrawElementsInstancedEXT (iPhone 5). I tried different meshes and found out that FPS falls by hundred of times if total number of indices (number of instances multiplied by number of indices of mesh) exceeds approximately 4 mln. I would add that drawing using glDrawElements slows down in a similar manner in this case.

And there is another problem.
If a number of instances exceeds 65535, glDrawElementsInstancedEXT draws depending on the number of instances drawn in the very first call of glDrawElementsInstancedEXT:

- if the number of instances in the very first call is less than 65536, then the following calls draw only the first 65535 instances
- if the number of instances in the very first call exceeds 65535, then the following calls draw the full number of instances.

It looks like a bug in a driver.